# Sum of distinct members of a sequence lie in the same set

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

Suppose a sequence is defined as $a_n=a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}$ with $a_0=-1$ and $a_1=2$. Now, do there exist any $m,n$ such that $a_m+a_n=a_{n'}$ except $m=n+1$ or $m=n-1$?, I.e., whether the sum of two non-consecutive terms of the sequence can be a term of the sequence? I think the difference equation satisfied by the sequence may give some clue, but am unable to get any simplification. Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: I assume you don't want us to simply solve for $a_n$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: This is almost like the Fibonacci numbers, which have a closed form called Binet's formula.  Presumably, you do not sound as though you want this formula.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt No, I do not want the formula. But, whether the sum of two different non-consecutive terms in the sequence would give rise to another term of the sequence is my question

Comment: This is the Fibonacci numbers with every other term negated

Comment: @ColmBhandal so, how does that help?

Comment: So can we answer whether there are two Fibonnaci numbers whose sum or difference is also a Fibonnaci number? Seems like that question would be more widely studied.

Comment: @ColmBhandal exactly, now whether that is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see that this sequence is the Fibonnaci sequence with every other term negated:

$$-1, 2, -3, 5, -8, 13, \ldots$$

So if two terms of this sequence added to another term of the sequence, we'd either have:

$$F_n + F_m = F_k$$ for three Fibonnaci numbers, or we'd have

$$F_n - F_m = F_k$$ for three Fibonnaci numbers, but then taking the $F_m$ across, we'd have again the first case. So, we just need to consider the equation:

$$F_n + F_m = F_k$$

WLOG, let's say $n > m$. Then we know that the only $m$ that allows the sum to be Fibonacci is $n-1$, else the sum falls too short. In other words, the only valid sum is:

$$F_n + F_{n-1} = F_{n+1}$$

To hammer the point home one more time, suppose $j < n - 1$. Then we have:

$$F_n < F_n + F_j < F_{n+1}$$

So $F_n + F_j$, being strictly between two consecutive Fibonnaci numbers, can't itself be part of the sequence.

Comment: Whether Binet's Formula is of some use here?

Comment: Don't know, I've never seen it or used it before!